# Why does my AssignmentExpression automatically become a return statement when I put it in a LambdaExpression

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I'm making an assignment inside a LambdaExpression.  For some reason, the lambda is treating that assignment as the return type of the lambda as well.

```
var localIntVar = Expression.Variable(typeof(int));
var assign = Expression.Assign(localIntVar, Expression.Constant(5));
var block = Expression.Block(new ParameterExpression[]{localIntVar}, assign);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(block);

lambda.Dump();
```

The generated lambda is of type `Func<Int32>`.  I expected it to be `Action`.  If I add an `Expression.Empty()` to the end of the block, it works as expected.

```
var localIntVar = Expression.Variable(typeof(int));
var assign = Expression.Assign(localIntVar, Expression.Constant(5));
var block = Expression.Block(new ParameterExpression[]{localIntVar}, assign, Expression.Empty());
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(block);

lambda.Dump();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of the [`Expression.Block` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267906(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When the block expression is executed, **it returns the value of the last expression in the block.**

So it is not the assignment expression is treated as return value but any expression which stands as the last parameter of the `Expression.Block` method.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are invoking [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267906%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of Block() which accepts a collection of ParameterExpression. In the second example you are invoking [a different overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323895%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of Block() that specifies a block expression with no variables.

Try this:

```
var localIntVar = Expression.Variable(typeof(int));
var assign = Expression.Assign(localIntVar, Expression.Constant(5));
var block = Expression.Block(localIntVar, assign, Expression.Empty());
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(block);
```

Comment: I think this still produces a Func<Int32>.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267906%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the one that's being invoked in the second example.